# Why can't App.xaml locate the Bootstrapper?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml

I am using Caliburn Micro MVVM, and I have not been having this problem until I restarted Visual Studio. I am receiving this warning in `App.xaml`:

[image]

This is the file:

```
<Application x:Class="Files.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Files">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <local:Bootstrapper x:Key="Bootstrapper"/>
                </ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Themes/SideMenu.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Themes/DirectoryBar.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Themes/SearchBar.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Themes/Scrollbar.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I do not remember having made any changes when this error occurred. I am also receiving the following error in the error list:

[image]

The following is in `Bootstrapper.cs`:

```
using Caliburn.Micro;
using Files.ViewModels;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace Files
{
    public class Bootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
    {
        public Bootstrapper()
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            DisplayRootViewForAsync<ShellViewModel>();
        }
    }
}
```

I am unsure what the source of this problem is.

EDIT:
Here is `App.xaml.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace Files
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: could you show your app.xaml.cs ...in case of..some errors disappear when you compile

Comment: sometimes a file could be corrupted, i suggest you to clean the solution and regenerate

Comment: The general approach to odd namespace errors is. 1: Check the output window (the error window may not be correct). 2: Do a clean rebuild. 3: Clean your working directory using your revision control system. 4: [Clean visual studio caches](https://dotnetrevisited.blogspot.com/2020/06/how-to-clear-visual-studio-cache.html)

Comment: I have tried all solutions outlined in these comments, the problem still remains.

Comment: I have also uninstalled VS and installed the latest version, the problem still remains. I have also tried making a new project in a new solution, the problem still remains.